# JS video loading SOMETIMES works, other times Uncaught (in promise) DOMException?

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

Implementing video in a three JS texture and Im having an issue where my video SOMETIMES loads without errors, other times I get `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException` and no video loads.

I think the issue is I need to wait for the video to load before I can set it to a material:

```
var video = document.createElement( 'video' );
    video.src = './src/images/sintel.ogv';
    video.load(); // must call after setting/changing source
    video.preload = 'auto';
    video.autoload = true;
    video.play();


    var texture = new THREE.VideoTexture( video );
    texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    texture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

    // var runnerTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/run.png' );
    // annie = new TextureAnimator( runnerTexture, 10, 1, 10, 75 ); // texture, #horiz, #vert, #total, duration.
    var runnerMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, side:THREE.DoubleSide } );
```

I don't know what to do here. Tried adding preload to the video but didn't work.

Comment: This error will occur with Safari since Ogg Vorbis is not supported by this browser. Besides, autoplay with sound does not work at least in Chrome for security reasons. Similar to the [three.js examples](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_video), a user interaction is required before starting the video.

Comment: Any more details about the error? Fuller message, and at what line in the code it occurs?

Comment: @I-- it just says unhandled promise, nothing else.

Comment: @Mugen87 I just switched to mp4 and still having the same error

Comment: Does it work if you do this before starting the video: `video.muted = true;`?